# delete, fetch a item that belong to another in a relationship in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

I create a relationship between Task and ToDo in CoreData. Each Tasks can contain lots of toDos but toDos only belong to specific task. If I delete a task, all toDos belong to that task should also be deleted so I set the relationship to Cascade. The code I have now is only for fetch and delete all toDos. I know how to save toDos to a specific task but I don't how to fetch and delete them. My code is all like get all toDos, e.g.

```
static func retrieveToDo() -> [ToDo] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<ToDo>(entityName: "ToDo")
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return results
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error)")
    }
    return []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ABOUT RELATION**

If you've a relation between `Task` and `ToDo` entity as `toDos` and `task` respectively then you'll find a property as `toDos` of type `NSSet` in `Task` model class, `task` of type `Task` in `ToDo` model class.

**ACCESS RELATION**

If you've an object of type `Task` can easily fetch the `toDos` of that task by using `taskObj.toDos` it'll return a `NSSet` of `ToDo` type.

If you've an object of type `ToDo` can easily fetch the `task` of that toDo by using `toDoObj.task` it'll return a `Task`.

**FOR DELETE**

If you delete the `Task` object the `toDos` related to that task will be deleted automatically.

If you delete `ToDo` object then it'll automatically deleted from the respective `Task`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
class CoreDataHelper {
class func getFetchRequestforModelClass(_ className : NSManagedObject.Type) -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {

    let stringClassName = String(stringInterpolationSegment: className)

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: stringClassName, in: ManagedObjectContext)

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    return request
}

class func getAllTask() -> [Task]?{
    let fetchRequest = CoreDataHelper.getFetchRequestforModelClass(Task.self)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "task_id", ascending: true)]
    var fetchedEntities:[Task]?
    do
    {
        fetchedEntities = try ManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Task]
    }catch{
    }
    return fetchedEntities
}}
```

Comment: can you write me some sample code please? I still don't know how to write.

Comment: I am still confused..cry...how about the delete toDos from specific task?

Comment: Just delete the toDo object it'll automatically remove from the NSSet, no need to do anything else